# Update a HasMany records

Tags: cakephp-3.0, has-many

I am converting a working app from cakephp2 to cakephp3.  I'm struggling to get a form that updates hasMany records to work.

The app has the following structure:

MODELS:

```
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class AwardsTable extends Table
{
  public function initialize(array $config)
  {
   $this->hasMany('Levels', ['sort' => 'sort_order']);
  }
}


namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Award extends Entity
{
  protected $_accessible = [
    'name'            =>  true,
    'url'             =>  true,
    'organisation'    => true,
    'detail'          =>  true,
    'logo'            =>  true,
    'levels'          =>  true,
    'Levels'          =>  true
   ];

}
```

IN THE FORM:

```
<?= $this->Form->input("levels.$i.name",  'label'=>false,'type'=>'text','value' => $award->name]);?>
<?= $this->Form->input("levels.$i.id", ['value' => $award->id]); ?>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$this->Awards->patchEntity($award, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Levels']]);         
if ($this->Awards->save($award)) {
    $this->Flash->success(__('Your Award has been saved.'));
    $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

This seems inline with what is recommended here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs

I've tried a few variations with capitalisation & pluralisation. The award data saves correctly but the associated levels data does not save.

What am I missing to get the has_many association data to save?

EDIT: Example Data array submitted:

```
    2016-01-28 23:32:56 Error: Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [name] => test award
    [organisation] => test org
    [url] => http://www.example.com
    [detail] => 
    [levels] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test 1
                    [id] => 4
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test
                    [id] => 16
                )

        )

    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: And "_with no luck_" translates to what kind of specific problem? The data isn't being patched in? It is patched in but not being saved? Saving fails and the entity is being decorated with errors? ...?

Comment: It doesn't save the levels data.  the other award data saves.  it doesn't give an error or log anything to the debug log

Answer (score 1):

In LevelEntity verify if 'id' is accessible

```
protected $_accessible = [
    '*' => true,
    'id' => true,
];
```